# But can't the $\pi$th root of $-1$ also be $\frac1{e^i}$?

Tags: solution-verification, complex-numbers, radicals

So I was bored, and decided to do some math for fun. I came up with $$\text{Find all solutions to }\sqrt[\pi]{-1}\text{ other than just }e^i$$which I thought that I might be able to do. Here is my attempt at doing so:

Know: $\sqrt[\pi]{-1}=e^i$, however to find another solution (if possible)$$e^i=e^{\left((-1)^\frac12\right)}=x$$$$\implies(-1)^i=\ln(x)$$$$\implies\dfrac12i\pi=\ln(\ln(x))$$$$\implies i\pi=2\ln(\ln(x))$$Setting $\ln(x)=a$,$$i\pi=2\ln(a)$$$$-1=a^2$$$$-(a)^2-1=0$$$$\implies a^2+1=0$$$$\implies a=\pm i$$$$\ln(x)=\pm i$$$$x=e^{\pm i}$$$$\therefore x=e^i,\dfrac1{e^i}$$

---

### My question

---

Am I right in assuming that $\sqrt[\pi]{-1}=e^{\pm i}$, or is there only one solution to $\sqrt[\pi]{-1}=x$?

Comment: for odd $n,$   $e^{i n \pi}  = -1  \; \; \; \; \; \; $

Comment: How did you define the logarithm for complex numbers?

Comment: @LL3.14 $\ln(ab)=\ln(a)+\ln(b)$, $-x=-1\cdot x$, $-1=e^{i\pi}$, $\ln(e^{a})=a$

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work, since you would get $i\pi = \ln(e^{i\pi}) =   \ln(-1) = \ln(e^{3i\pi}) = 3i\pi$

Comment: When making up problems for yourself, you ought to be thinking about the meanings of the expressions you're using. What is a $\pi$th root? Are you looking for complex numbers $z$ satisfying $z^\pi=-1$? What does it mean to [raise a complex number to an irrational power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Non-integer_powers_of_complex_numbers)? Asking these kinds of questions instead of just manipulating symbols will make you a better mathematician.

Comment: Notice that when you have an integer root, square cubed etc. There are infinitely many roots however they repeat. e.g. for squareroot you have k=0,1 unique which periodically repeat in value for 2,3,4,5 etc. However, where you have an irrational number there is no value of k which will repeat and so there are infinitely many unique roots

Comment: I see you accepted user531544 answer. See my comment about that answer.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Such problems may be solved in a systematic way.
You have $z=-1=e^{\pi i}$ in standard form and look for (all) complex numbers $w=z^{\frac{1}{\pi}}$.

In general, you employ $e^{2\pi i n}=1$ for all $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ and thus write

$$w=(ze^{2\pi i n})^{\frac{1}{\pi}}
=(e^{\pi i}e^{2\pi i n})^{\frac{1}{\pi}}
=(e^{\pi i(2n+1)})^{\frac{1}{\pi}}
=e^{i(2n+1)} = e^{im} 
$$
for all odd integer $m$.

So your set of all solutions is $W=\{\ldots ,e^{-3i},e^{-i},e^{i},e^{3i},e^{5i},... \}$

Comment: Be careful, it seems to me that you are using the "exponent rule" $(z^a)^b = a^{a b}$ which is, in general, not valid when dealing with complex numbers.

Comment: @jjagmath, I believe I only use $(e^a)^b=e^{ab}$ for Euler number $e$ and arbitrary complex $a$ and $b$. I'd appreciate to learn if you can point out if any of the operations I use above is not valid (even for other numbers than $z=-1$ and exponent $1/\pi$)

Comment: Take the specific case of $(e^z)^{1/\pi}$. This is actually a multivalued expression defined as $e^{\tfrac{1}{\pi}\text{Log}(e^z)} = e^{\tfrac{1}{\pi}(z+2\pi i k)}$. One of that values, when $k=0$, is $e^{\tfrac{z}{\pi}}$, but for other $k$'s you'll get different values.

Comment: The specific step where there is a problem is $(e^{\pi i(2n+1)})^{\frac{1}{\pi}}
=e^{i(2n+1)}$. The LHS is multivalued, but the RHS takes only one value.

Comment: Thank you. Is it correct that the set of all expressions on the LHS of your equation (i.e. for all integer n) equals the set of all values on the RHS? If so, I have a notational problem but not a logical problem. [Sorry for the delay.]

Comment: I think, the set of all (multiple) values of $(e^a)^b$,  as used in the example answering the question, covers exactly all solutions. If not, can someone state a counterexample where the answer actually fails?

Answer (score 2):

For complex numbers $z$ and $w$ the "function" $z^w$ is multivaluated, and it's defined by $z^w = e^{w\ \text{Log}\ z}$ for all the posible values of $\text{Log}\ z$.

Then

$$(-1)^{1/\pi} = e^{\tfrac{1}{\pi}\text{Log}(-1)} = e^{\tfrac{1}{\pi}(\pi i +2\pi i k)} = e^{(2k+1)i} = \cos(2k+1) + i\sin(2k+1)$$ where $k\in \Bbb Z$.

When $k=0$ we get the principal value $e^i = \cos 1+ i\sin 1$, and for $k=-1$ we get also the value $e^{-i} = \cos 1- i\sin 1$, but those are just two from an infinity of values that the expression takes.